# Data not refreshing/loading properly when loading Excel Workbook into COM object in Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, vba, com

So I am loading an excel spreadsheet using win32. I then slice the spreadsheet taking rows 8-4000 and columns 1-65.

Columns 1-16 are all static data. The columns thereafter are all formulas (e.g. performing division) or pulling data in from Bloomberg using Bloomberg's Excel API (e.g. =BDP(E9&" corp","CRNCY") ).

Now my issue is that excel will not update any of the columns 17-65? when I load it manually and it works perfectly.. 
maybe you can see the error in my ways below... Thank you.

(I've tagged VBA since the python wrapper must pass VBA-like code; or so I understand. So if any VBA coders have insights into this it'd be great)

```
import win32com.client as win32


def open_workbook(xlapp, xlfile, password=None):

    try:

        xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks("LAP.xlsm")

    except Exception as e:
        print("No 1. Error: ", e)
        try:
            xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(xlfile, Password=password, UpdateLinks=0)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            xlwb = None

    return xlwb


def main(file, password=None):

    xlapp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application") 

    xlapp.DisplayAlerts = True
    xlapp.Visible = True
    print(check.check_file(file, xlapp))

    if not check.check_file(file, xlapp):
        xlwb = open_workbook(xlapp, xlfile=file, password=password)
    else:
        print("Error")  # TODO what would we do if we can't open the file, try again, prompt user?...


    # The resources sheet contains Currency Exchange Rates used for formula in 'Data' Sheet
    res = xlwb.Sheets('Resources') 
    # The Calculate() stuff is my attempt at fixing the problem
    res.EnableCalculation = False
    res.EnableCalculation = True
    res.Calculate()

    # This is the Main Sheet of interest - it is later loaded into a Panda's Dataframe
    xlws = xlwb.Sheets('Data') 
    last_col = xlws.UsedRange.Columns.Count 
    last_row = xlws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    #All of this Calcualte() stuff is my attempt at fixing the problem - to no prevail 
    xlws.EnableCalculation = False
    xlws.EnableCalculation = True
    xlws.Calculate()
    xlws.Columns(17).Calculate()
    xlws.Columns(16).Calculate()
    xlws.Columns(18).Calculate()

    xlws.Range(xlws.Cells(8,17), xlws.Cells(last_row,17)).Formula = \
    xlws.Range(xlws.Cells(8,17),xlws.Cells(last_row,17)).Formula


    # This content will be loaded in DataFrame
    content = xlws.Range(xlws.Cells(8,1), xlws.Cells(last_row, last_col)).Value

    print(len(content), type(content))
    print(content[:10])  
    # The final print statement reveals that many of the formula driven columns are 0,N/A etc..
```

Comment: Maybe `xlapp.CalculateFull` will god work, it's refresing all acros entire excel app.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working; I am thinking it may be a Bloomerbg.xla (the Add In) issue. When I load the Excel file using the Python Console (so that I can code dynamically) the Bloomberg tab Refresh All button returns an error... Now I have verified using xlapp.AddIns that it is indeed installed etc. so will do some research on this and get back to you. Thanks